# Disable all events in Print preview mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css

In chrome print preview mode, I can able to click some links and it's navigating to that urls. I want to disable all events in chrome print preview mode. I tried multiple ways none is worked out.

Comment: You could do something like keeping an transperent overlay div over your whole body content when at print mode. @VinothKanna

Comment: Yes i did it already but still i can able to click links

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. Using CSS, in print view, disable click for all anchor tags.

```
@media print
{
  a {pointer-events: none; cursor: default;}
}
```